# How do you run X.org and GNOME on WSL?

Tags: gnome, xorg, xinit

After what feels like years and years of futile attempts and google searches, I have finally decided to come here. As a beginner to linux, I really don't know stuff. After going through countless tutorials, I have been able to get through every problem except one. (though afterwards there will probably be plenty more to come)

I am getting this error running `startx`:

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: linux Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux DESKTOP-2DV5IQB 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64
Kernel command line: initrd=\initrd.img panic=-1 pty.legacy_count=0 nr_cpus=8
Build Date: 14 December 2021  02:14:13PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Apr 28 21:10:03 2022
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Function not implemented)
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Function not implemented)
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

When I tried to run `xinit`:

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: linux Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux DESKTOP-2DV5IQB 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64
Kernel command line: initrd=\initrd.img panic=-1 pty.legacy_count=0 nr_cpus=8
Build Date: 14 December 2021  02:14:13PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Apr 28 21:11:39 2022
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Function not implemented)
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Function not implemented)
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

I really don't know what to do at this point. All I wanted to do was follow the "simple" instructions [on the ubuntu website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems) to install GNOME!

My question basically is, am I doing this right? If so, why am I getting these errors, and what can I do to fix them? If not, how should I do it?

I am using WSL, which my many queries have brought me to suspecting that might be half of the problem. I am also probably very wrong about this as well.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: WSL is still a work in progress. Until recently there has been no support for GUI applications. If your goal is to install a desktop environment, WSL is really not a good choice especially if you are "a beginner to Linux". If you want to run Ubuntu Desktop on Windows, it's going to be much easier and stable to run Ubuntu on a VM like VirtualBox.

Comment: The instructions you linked are not pertinent to WSL.  It's important to realize that WSL is not the same as running Ubuntu on bare metal or even in a virtual machine.  It may be a goal for future versions of WSL to easily run GUI applications, but for now it's really only stable and useful for using Linux command line utilities on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the information! This is really helpful :)

Comment: Try following this guide. I was able to get this working a while back. https://gist.github.com/Ta180m/e1471413f62e3ed94e72001d42e77e22 It does say it works specifically on ubuntu 20.04, so if you're running into issues be sure to try that specific version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install VcXsrv in order to run a X server in Windows. I leave you [this guide](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/linux-desktop-windows-subsystem/#:%7E:text=Windows%20Subsystem%20for%20Linux%20(WSL,install%20and%20run%20Linux%20software).

In WSL update the system, install the desktop environment:

```shell
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install lxde
```

GNOME in your case. Then set the environment variable DISPLAY you need to provide the Windows WSL IP address like following:

```shell
export DISPLAY=<address>:0
```

Replace  with the corresponding value. You can get the address going to the PowerShell and executing `ipconfig`. You'll see it under the WSL section (IPv4).

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/what-does-libgl-always-indirect-1-actually-do) an explanation on why you may need to set LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT.

```shell
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
```

When you run XLaunch on Windows (provided by VcXsrv):

1. Display settings: Choose "One large window"
2. Display number: 0 (the number next to the IP address when you set DISPLAY)
3. Select how to start clients: Choose "Start no client"
4. Extra settings: The default and "Disable access control too" (I don't know if this cause any security issue)

Then on WSL you can use `startx` and launch the desktop environment.

When I did this I also install `x11-apps` and run `xeyes` to test if it works.

EDIT: You may want to try setting DISPLAY as follows to automatically get the IP address:

```shell
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0
```

Comment: You should include the details from the guide in your answer, in case it goes away.

Comment: WSL is a moving target, this answer will probably be inaccurate in 3-6 months.  It might be nice to revisit this question when the next version of WSL is released.

Comment: I edited the answer Artur.